# constructor that takes the name of the file that is supposed to hold a representation of the maze

Tags: java, recursion, file-io

I am trying to create a maze game in java. I want to read a file in constructor. My class name is GameBoard and i want to create constructor that takes the name of the file that is supposed to hold a representation of the maze. My constructor is public GameBoard(String sFileName). How can i initialize that in constructor?

Comment: Please read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a field called

```
private String sFileName;
```

In the constructor

```
this.sFileName = sFileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a File or a name in the constructor, it depends on how the class is defined:

```
File file;
GameBoard(String name){
    file = new File(name);
}
```

or

```
String fileName;
GameBoard(String name){
    fileName = name;
}
```